# Why MySQL server is not starting?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I faced many troubled with MySQL - too many applications related to MySQL was installed

I totally removed MySQL from my MAC_OS - any folder have "mysql" keyword had been removed && all the applications which related to MySQL

I started again from scratch by installing MySQL community and MySQL Workbench

now - MySQL server are not starting
 , every time I click on "Start MySQL Server" it load but nothing happens

I think - I don't have enough info about why I have this issue , but any tips will be helpful

[image]

Comment: if i remember it properly there is an issue with the auto startup on macos. You need to start it manually on reboot

Comment: It doesn't start for the reason stated in the log files.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest to remove .Log files from MySql data folder. Since it's new installation there is no risk. MySql should definitely start